# Children waking up 50 years after nuclear war

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

It has a fantasy flavor, but it's about a few children that are preserved in really high towers during a nuclear apocalypse. They're revived something like 50 years after the war and oriented into their roles as saviors of the barren landscape by this old dude who's been really scarred by radiation.  In the end he turns out to be the main character's father. That's all I remember. I think it was part of a series. I know this is really common, but I really want to read it again. I remember it looking like it was from the early 90s, late 80s? I could be wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this would be the Seven Sleepers series. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have its own article.

Book list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert_Morris#Seven_Sleepers_series

Goodreads: http://www.goodreads.com/series/42182-seven-sleepers

Description: "Josh Adams, 14, awakes from a 50-year sleep. Ancient prophecy commands him and the other Sleepers to unite in battle against the evil priests, and combat the doubt that threatens their faith."

Comment: The Goodreads reviews seem to clinch it.