# Help identify book about a post apocalyptic world, children waking up from stasis

Tags: story-identification, novel

This has been driving me nuts, but I remember reading a science fiction novel as a kid, it might have been required reading but I honestly cannot remember.

What details I do recall is that this was set in a post apocalyptic world and over the course of the book, more and more children were discovered and awoken from stasis after hundreds or thousands of years.  Can anyone throw out book suggestions with similar details they know of?  I can look up the plots of said suggestions and it should refresh my memory if it's right.

Comment: Do you remember how long ago you read it, maybe how old it seemed at the time. Also take a look at [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if it'll help jog your memory

Comment: It would have been in the mid 90's, it felt like it might have been written in the 70's or 80's.  It's been so long.  It seemed like there was a purpose behind finding more and waking them up, some sort of mission or reason they were put to sleep and not adults.

Comment: Actually, the more I think of it, it might have been written even earlier.  I think it was a required read in middle school or possibly high school.

Comment: There are similarities to the [Seven Sleepers series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83918/children-waking-up-50-years-after-nuclear-war/83978#83978)